# Topological spaces. Open and closed maps.

Tags: general-topology, functions

Give some examples of continuous topological maps, which is neither open nor closed

I'm a beginner in functional analysis and can't understand how a continuous map can be neither open nor closed. Further more a continuous map can be either closed and open at the same time?

Comment: For your last question, consider the identity map from a space to itself.

Comment: This was discussed many times, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809374/maps-from-subsets-of-mathbbr2-that-are-either-open-closed-continuous?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the sine function $\sin\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, for instance:

- it is not open because $\mathbb R$ is open, but $\sin(\mathbb R)=[-1,1]$, which is not open.
- it is not closed, because $C=\left\{2n\pi+\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is closed, but $\sin(C)=\left\{\sin\left(\frac1n\right)\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$, which is not closed.

Comment: Can you please explain why sin(C) is not closed?

Comment: Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac1n\right)=0\notin\sin(C)$.

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$$
from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$? Its range is $(0,1]$.